# combine dataset using if else{} in for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, tidyr, data-manipulation

I need a function that removes the factor values of more than two, in this case, `cyl`.  Must take the mean of the numeric values and the `prop.table()=1` for factor values.  And at the end, it should create a dataset as the expected answer. Many thanks in advance.

```
`head(mtcars)
    mtcars$vs <- as.factor(mtcars$vs) 
    mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl) # sholuld be removed from the final dataset
    #var <- colnames(mtcars); var
    Summ.Continuous <- tab.prob <- out <- NULL
    
    myfunction <- function(var,df) {
      
      df <- df[, !sapply(df, is.character)] #Remove Character Columns
      
      for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
        if(is.factor(df[,j])){ 
          tab.prob[j] <- prop.table(table(df[,j]))
          
        } else {
          Summ.Continuous[j] <- describe(df)$mean
          
        }} 
      out <- list(tab.prob, Summ.Continuous)
      return(out)}
    
    myfunction(var, mtcars)
```

Expected Answer

```
  mp 20.09 
    cyl NA 
    disp 230.7 
    hp 146.7  
    drat 3.597 
    wt 3.217 
    qsec 17.85 
    vs 0.4375 #prob.table based on 1
    am 0.4062 
    gear 3.688 
    carb 2.812 `
```

Comment: how do you get `0.4` for vs?

Comment: prop.table(table(mtcar$vs)) = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `tidyverse` we can conditionally select using `where`, and summarise conditionally using `across`, for example:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(vs = as.factor(vs),
         cyl = as.factor(cyl)) %>%
  select(!where(~ is.factor(.x) && levels(.x) > 2)) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean),
            across(where(is.factor), ~ prop.table(table(.x))[2]))

       mpg     disp       hp     drat      wt     qsec      am   gear   carb     vs
1 20.09062 230.7219 146.6875 3.596563 3.21725 17.84875 0.40625 3.6875 2.8125 0.4375
```

This can be used together with the `tidylog` package to inform what happened at each step, here useful to notify that `cyl` has been dropped from the output.

```
library(tidylog)
~ previous code here

mutate: converted 'cyl' from double to factor (0 new NA)
        converted 'vs' from double to factor (0 new NA)
select: dropped one variable (cyl)
summarise: now one row and 10 columns, ungrouped
```

Comment: very much appreciated, yet I wonder if there is a way to keep the name order too?

Comment: im not sure what you mean by name order ...?

Comment: qsec vs am. like the colnames(mtcars) changes. is there an option to fix that? It is not important though.